# DataFrame: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou tentando receber os maiores valores da coluna `Valor Pago`. No Jupyter.

```
top_10_empenho = portal[['Descrição', 'Valor Pago']].head(10).set_index('Descrição').sort_values('Valor Pago', ascending=True)
top_10_empenho.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(11,7), grid=False, color='darkred', legend=False)
plt.title('teste1')
plt.xlabel('teste2')
plt.show()
```

Mas aparece a seguinte mensagem.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-6a6f04dd7619> in <module>
      1 #Os 10 Empenhos com Maior Valor Liquido
      2 top_10_empenho = portal[['Descrição', 'Valor Pago']].head(10).set_index('Descrição').sort_values('Valor Pago', ascending=True)
----> 3 top_10_empenho.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(11,7), grid=False, color='darkred', legend=False)
      4 
      5 plt.title('teste1')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2940                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   2941                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2942                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   2943     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   2944 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   1971                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1972                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 1973                  **kwds)
   1974 
   1975 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1799         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   1800 
-> 1801     plot_obj.generate()
   1802     plot_obj.draw()
   1803     return plot_obj.result

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in generate(self)
    247     def generate(self):
    248         self._args_adjust()
--> 249         self._compute_plot_data()
    250         self._setup_subplots()
    251         self._make_plot()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _compute_plot_data(self)
    365         if is_empty:
    366             raise TypeError('Empty {0!r}: no numeric data to '
--> 367                             'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
    368 
    369         self.data = numeric_data

TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Comment: Tenta fazer  :  top_10_empenho['Valor Pago'].plot(kind='barh', ...)

Comment: @LeonardoBohac, cara assim funciona de boa. Mas vc sabe me dizer como fazer para ter junto a coluna "Descrição"? Pois quando coloco assim:   portal[["Descrição", "Valor Pago"]].head(20).plot.bar()
--- O erro volta a aparecer  | TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot |

Comment: Acho que é porque você está querendo colocar no mesmo plot (na mesma chamada de plot) dois tipos de dados diferentes (imagino que o campo “descrição” não seja numérico. Talvez você consiga exibir os dois colocando na linha de baixo o mesmo código, porém com top_10_empenho[‘Descrição’].plot(...).

Comment: @LeonardoBohac, Tipo descrição são os nomes de **entidades pessoas físicas e jurídicas e valor pago são os valores gostos**. Queria exibir no gráfico a Entidade seguida de seu valor gasto. Quando coloco as duas linhas não é exibido os valores da coluna valor pago. `portal["Valor Pago"].head(20).value_counts().sort_values().plot.bar()
portal["Descrição"].head(20).value_counts().sort_values().plot.bar()
#Definido Títulos
plt.title('As 10 Primeiras entidades')
plt.xlabel('Entidades')
plt.ylabel('Quant de Empenhos lançados')
plt.show()`

Comment: Você conhece a biblioteca *matplotlib* ? Ela é boa para lidar com plots, em vez de usar diretamente a biblioteca de plotagem do pandas.

Comment: @LeonardoBohac, Não! Mais vou tentar pesquisar para substituir minha chamada para o grafico.

Comment: Olá! Conseguir unir as colunas utilizando a função **crosstab**. O código ficou assim: 
`cruztab_dv = pd.crosstab(portal['Valor Pago'], portal['Descrição'])
cruztab_dv.head()`. Mais ainda não conseguir exibir um gráfico.